# Pass JavaScript variables to HTML using class

Tags: javascript, html

Ultra noob question
I have variable in JavaScript and I have to use it in HTML multiple times
I've tried using `document.getElementById("").innerHTML = x`, but that requires ID's, and since they can be used only once, it won't be the best solution because I'm using it a lot of times...

```html
<div>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <!-- I want to pass value of x to all of spans bellow -->
    <p>Value of x: <span class="value-of-x"></span></p>
    <p>Value of x: <span class="value-of-x"></span></p>
    <p>Value of x: <span class="value-of-x"></span></p>
</div>
<script>
    var x = 100;
</script>
```

I'm really sorry if it's a dumb question, but I'm struggling with this for a solid hour and nothing works for me
Every suggestion welcome

> Edit - typos

Comment: use `document.querySelectorAll()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`document.QuerySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select all spans. It uses a css selector to select all elements that match the selector.

```js
var spans = document.querySelectorAll("span.value-of-x");
spans.forEach((element) => {
    element.innerText = x;
});
```

With the example above you can select all the spans with the class `value-of-x` and loop through them to set the innerText of the spans to `x`.